# how to get variable value from a mysql fetch in php and use it to create another query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is my code with my output

```
 <?php
 $data = mysql_query("select * from request, users where request.user_id =  users.id and request.user_id = $user_id")  or die(mysql_error());
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";    
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
 {
     Print "<tr class='my_loans_tr'>"; 
     print "<td  class='detail'>"  .$info['loan_id'] . "</td> ";
     Print " <td class='admin_amount'>".$info['amount'] . "</td> "; 
     Print " <td class='admin_points'>".$info['points'] . "</td> ";  
     Print " <td class='admin_date'>".$info['req_date'] . " </td>"; 
     Print " <td class='admin_status'>".$info['status'] . " </td>"; 
     Print " <td class='admin_cancelled'>".$info['cancelled_loan'] . " </td></tr>"; 
     Print "</tr>"; 
 }  
 Print "</table>";
?>
```

**output**

[image]

The `loan id` is within the database, there is a second table named `collected`, that has info for each `loan id` (3 rows minimum of info based on same `loan id`)

How can I get each `id` from the query, click on it, get the current `id` and declare it as a value so I can execute another query which is,

```
select * from collected where loan id = "$loan_id clicked";
```

I have searched for `javascript` and `jquery` but I am not able to get it working with the `post method`, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: The PHP is not available once the page has loaded. You'll need to send an AJAX request to a PHP page to retrieve the additional data.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".detail").click(function(){
                       var obj      = $(this);
                        var objValue = obj.text();
                        $.ajax({
                url: '/page/to/ajax/dispatcher.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'id':objValue
                },
               
            });   });    });
</script>